# Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded webpack riquire consumes error with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, render

I'm currently having this issue with my React app where when you get to the first page it appears blank. The problem started when I made some changes related to apollo client, since I'm using to fetch some data used in the app, the thing is that the changes that I made are not even giving a clue about why the stack would exceed its limit, and even more weird is that when you refresh several times the error disappears. Any clue about how to solve this?
[First time you open the app] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv2gc.png)
[After several times the error disappears] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/er1xw.png)

I've been reading about some errors related to the webpack but none of them are similar to this one. Help please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.